# How to show $\min f(x)+g(x) \leq \min f(x) + \max g(x)$ $\forall x$.

Tags: inequality, optimization

Let $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $f,g: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

Also, suppose that $f(x),g(x) \geq 0$

Show $\min_x \{f(x)+g(x)\} \leq \min_x f(x) + \max_x g(x)$

Comment: Did you try anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The notation implies that these functions attain their minimum values and that $g$ attains its maximum value. Let $x_0\in\Bbb R^n$ be such that $f(x_0)=\min_xf(x)$. Then

$$\begin{align*}
\min_x(f(x)+g(x))&\le f(x_0)+g(x_0)\\
&\le f(x_0)+\max_xg(x)\\
&=\min_xf(x)+\max_xg(x)\;.
\end{align*}$$

Suppose instead that $f$ and $g$ are bounded below, and $g$ is bounded above. Let $\epsilon>0$. There is an $x_\epsilon\in\Bbb R^n$ such that $f(x_\epsilon)-\inf_xf(x)<\epsilon$. Then

$$\begin{align*}
\inf_x(f(x)+g(x))&\le f(x_\epsilon)+g(x_\epsilon)\\
&<\inf_xf(x)+g(x_\epsilon)+\epsilon\\
&\le\inf_xf(x)+\sup_xg(x)+\epsilon
\end{align*}$$

for all $\epsilon>0$, so

$$\inf_x(f(x)+g(x))\le\inf_xf(x)+\sup_xg(x)\;.$$